# Setting active items in sencha touch container

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, containers

I am new in developing with sencha touch 2 , i have a container that contains a list of merchants

my container has the following code

```
Ext.define('WL.view.tablet.Container2', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'tabletContainer2',

    config: {

        layout: 'card',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'merchants',
                docked: 'left',
                width: 320,
                style: 'border-right: 2px solid #000'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'tabletSplash',
                flex: 1
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I want to show a list of merchants products along side with the merchants list when any of the merchants in the list is tapped, the two lists will be displayed side by side

i tried to use the following code to achieve that

```
    var products = Ext.widget('products');
    Ext.widget('tabletContainer').setActiveItem(products);
```

but it isn't working as expected for me , any ideas on how to set an active item inside my container?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `products` or `tabletContainer` are in your code but if you want to add any view to certain view with card layout, here is what I would do:

```
var prods = Ext.getCmp("WL.view.tablet.Products");
Ext.getCmp("tabletSplashId").animateActiveItem(prods, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left', duration : 500});
```

where `tabletSplashId` is ID of container in which you want to set this view.